# Google Backup and Sync starts over from the beginning and never finishes

Tags: online-backup

I installed Backup and Sync a couple of weeks ago instead of the Google Drive and Google Photos apps on my Windows PC. The problem is the new Backup and Sync never finishes. It is "syncing xxx out of 22300" and progresses quite slowly. I kept my PC on for two days straight and it only got half way. Whenever I restart Windows or restart the application, it seems like it starts all over again.

The funny thing is all my files are already backed up. It actually doesn't have to upload anything, since nothing has changed since the time the Google Drive and Google Photos apps worked.

The application version is 3.36.6884.5911.

Also tried reinstalling the application (downloaded latest version).

Comment: Does that number "22300" correlate to the number of files you're backing up?

Comment: Your not alone. I and many others have the same issue. Im running the same version as yours and its just uploading my whole photo (33897) collection again, which is already on google photos. It seems that with this new application you cannot just uploading directly to google photos anymore they have to be synced now with google drive and then if you have 'Upload newly added photos and videos to Google Photos' checked they will available in google photos.